# The Dirac-Ricci operator

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, spin-geometry, kahler-einstein-metric

If we consider a spin manifold $M$, we can define the Ricci curvature $Ricc (X,Y)$ which is a symmetric tensor, moreover the spinors are defined, so that we can define a Dirac-Ricci operator:
$$DR(\psi)=\sum_{ij}Ricc(e_i,e_j)[ e_i. \nabla_{e_j}\psi+e_j .\nabla_{e_i}\psi]$$
with $(e_i)$ an orthonormal basis.

If the manifold $M$ is an Einstein manifold ($Ricc=\lambda g$), then $DR=\lambda D$, the Dirac-Ricci operator is the Dirac operator $D$. Have we nice properties of such an operator in the general case?

Comment: The  Dirac operator  has an invariant definition as the composition $$ C^\infty(S)\stackrel{\nabla}{\to} C^\infty(T^*M\otimes S)\stackrel{c}{\to} C^\infty(S),$$ where $S$ denotes the spinor bundle and $c$ denotes  the Clifford  multiplication. I  do not  understand why the operator $DR$  is invariantly defined, If we replace the orthonormal moving frame $(e_i)$ by another, do we get the same thing?

Comment: If we have an expression like $\sum_i f(e_i,e_i)$ with $f$ bilinear, then it is always invariantly defined. We can indeed replace by another basis with an orthogonal automorphism and use $\sum_i a_{ij} a_{ik}=\delta_j^k$.